# CSS span hover not working

Tags: html, css

I want to show the dotted line when mouse hover the link, this method doesn't work.

```css
.text-link {
  color: #446CB3;
  font-family: "Tahoma";
  font-size: 15px;
 text-decoration:none;
}
.text-link:hover {
  text-decoration-style: dotted;
}
```

```html
<a href="URL" target="_blank" data-role="none">
  <span class="text-link">Click me</span>
</a>
```

Comment: [`text-decoration-style`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=text-decoration) is only supported by FireFox. The line you see is of the link, not of the span. And if you gave the span a line, it would fall together with the line of the link, so even in FireFox, the dotted line is probably not visible.

Comment: Agree with @GolezTrol. The text-decoration-style is badly supported. See the browser support here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-decoration-style.asp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't look like `text-decoration-style: dotted` is [supported in all browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-style):

[image]

For full support, you could use `border-bottom-style: dotted`.

In order for this to work, you need to remove the underline from the anchor element using `text-decoration: none`. Then just add a `border-bottom` to the element:

```css
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.text-link {
    color:#446CB3;
    font-family:"Tahoma";
    font-size:15px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
.text-link:hover {
    border-bottom-style: dotted;
}
```

```html
<a href="URL" target="_blank" data-role="none"><span class="text-link">Click me</span></a>
```

Comment: Note that `border-bottom` is not the same as an underline. The position of an underline is controlled by `text-underline-position`, which by default is `auto`. In most cases, that means an underline is close to the alphabetic baseline. However, a `border-bottom` behaves more like `text-underline-position: under`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

HTML:

```
<a href="URL" target="_blank" data-role="none"><span class="text-link">Click me</span></a>
```

CSS:

```
.text-link{
    color:#446CB3;
    font-family: "Tahoma";
    font-size:15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.text-link:hover{
    border-bottom: 2px dotted #446CB3;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What browser are you using?  The `text-decoration-style` is only supported by Firefox according to [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-decoration-style.asp)  if you turn off the `text-decoration-style`, the hover works fine.  see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/colost8rams/9g5tttta/1/).

Answer (score 1):

This is only supported by firefox, and it required the `-moz-` prefix.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-style

It should also applied on the `a` (*or remove it from the `a` and apply the full `text-decoration` on the `span`*(

```css
a {
  color: #446CB3;
  font-family: "Tahoma";
  font-size: 15px;
}
a:hover {
  -moz-text-decoration-style: dotted;
}
```

```html
<a href="URL" target="_blank" data-role="none">
  <span class="text-link">Click me</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

[`text-decoration-style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-style#Browser_compatibility) is only supported by Firefox 36 (which, at the time of writing, isn't yet released on the stable branch).

For earlier versions of Firefox, you can use the `-moz-` prefixed version of the property. In other browsers you can only fake it with borders.

Answer (score 0):

You should also set [`text-decoration-line`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-line) and maybe [`text-decoration-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-color).

Also consider using the [`text-decoration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration) shorthand property:

```css
.text-link:hover {
  text-decoration: underline dotted;
}
```

```css
.text-link {
  color: #446CB3;
  font-family: "Tahoma";
  font-size: 15px;
}
.text-link:hover {
  text-decoration: underline dotted;
}
```

```html
<a href="URL" target="_blank" data-role="none">
  <span class="text-link">Click me</span>
</a>
```

However, you will still have anchor's `text-decoration`. To prevent anchor's `text-decoration` from affecting `.text-link` (but not other content that could be in the anchor), you can use

```css
.text-link {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```css
.text-link {
  color: #446CB3;
  font-family: "Tahoma";
  font-size: 15px;
}
.text-link {
  display: inline-block;
}
.text-link:hover {
  text-decoration: underline dotted;
}
```

```html
<a href="URL" target="_blank" data-role="none">
  <span class="text-link">Click me</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.text-link {
  color: #446CB3;
  font-family: "Tahoma";
  font-size: 15px;
 text-decoration:none;
}
.text-link:hover {

  text-decoration:underline;
  text-decoration-style: dotted;
}
```

```html
<a href="URL" target="_blank" data-role="none" >
  <span class="text-link">Click me</span>
</a>
```

If you still want the underline and the dots on hover

```css
.text-link {
  color: #446CB3;
  font-family: "Tahoma";
  font-size: 15px;
 text-decoration:none;
}
.text-link:hover {

  text-decoration:underline;
  text-decoration-style: dotted;
}
```

```html
<a href="URL" target="_blank" data-role="none" class="text-link">
  <span>Click me</span>
</a>
```

if you just want dots on hover